# Android reduce space between back icon and header text

Tags: android, layout

i am new to android and facing with issue, any help will be grateful, thanks in advance.

I have added following code to create a back arrow on every page.

```
<activity
            android:name=".Leaves"
            android:parentActivityName=".Dashboard" />
```

Above code successfully created the back arrow on left top corner of screen.

Also i have added following class in my Java Class file to set header text

```
setTitle("Leave History");
```

Now the actual screen look like this

[image]

Actualy i want to reduce the space between back arrow and Title.
I have googled for long time but all the solution are related to toolbar, i am not using toolbar.
Will anyone put me on right track what mistake i doing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you make the toolbar? Share your code please

Comment: Its androids default toolbar. When we create new activity in android studio the default toolbar is added to your layout, its the same one

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the padding of the toolbar icon and title with these xml-attributes in your toolbar:

```
app:contentInsetStart
app:contentInsetEnd
app:contentInsetLeft
app:contentInsetRight
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation
```

If you set `app:contentInsetStart` to `0dp`, the space should dissappear.